# How to Query and filter in mongoDB in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to search my recipes by tags that are array of Strings 
and want to filter by tags

I know it will be

db.Recipe.find({$and:[{tags:"Desert"},{tags:"low-fat"}]}).pretty()

but I do not know how to write the query in java spring to be flexible 
flexible means numbers of filtered options can be vary

Answer (score 0):

Autowired the MongoTemplate

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Then use your filter inside the `andOperator()`

```
public void somemethod(){
    Query query=Query.query( new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("tags").is("Desert"),
        Criteria.where("anotherFilter").is("answer"),
        // write more filter
        )
    );

    List<Recipe> =mongoTemplate.find(query,Recipe.class);
    // do your stuffs
}
```

Comment: query does not have a andOperator
we should use   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
then pass criteria to Query query = new Query(criteria);
but how can  it be flexible to the tags ?
I means how can I iterate through tags and pass it to the andoperator ?? it doe not accepted

Comment: public List<Recipe> getRecipesByTags( List<String> tags){
        List<Criteria> criterias = null;
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        for (String tag :tags ) {
            criterias.add(Criteria.where("tags").is(tag));
        }
        criteria.andOperator();
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        return mongoTemplate.find(query,Recipe.class);

    }

Comment: you should use `$in` operator to make good performance if you pass multiple args to a field. Simple use `Criteri.where("blabla").in(listOfArgs);`

Comment: It was a mistake when i typed. I have edited the answer,

Comment: No I want to  get the tags from user and select recipes that have those tags in it, just it both side are list

Comment: What is the problem you face  when u use $in operator? This operator is for list of arguments where it can find your query form all tags in your documets

Answer (score 0):

we can get the list of tags from client 
then search it by that tags

@GetMapping("/recipe/searchByTags/{tags}")

```
public List<Recipe> getRecipesByTags(@PathVariable List<String> tags){
    Query query =  Query.query(
            Criteria.where("tags").all(tags)
    );
    return  mongoTemplate.find(query,Recipe.class);

}
```